# Exporting directions from Google to KML?

Tags: kml, export, android, google

I used Google to draw [directions from one location to another location](https://www.google.fr/maps/dir/48.8153938,2.3176049/70+Avenue+de+la+R%C3%A9publique,+94100+Saint-Maur-des-Foss%C3%A9s/@48.7956456,2.4066419,13z/data=!4m34!4m33!1m25!3m4!1m2!1d2.3422043!2d48.8003073!3s0x47e6716b7abedd9f:0xd38e571a035a2e34!3m4!1m2!1d2.3646927!2d48.7948301!3s0x47e673e064d34861:0xc712b60be7e29302!3m4!1m2!1d2.3881036!2d48.7925109!3s0x47e67395b2b494a7:0xd70309da104c540d!3m4!1m2!1d2.4260561!2d48.7996987!3s0x47e673169947adfd:0xad28503b548bf1a7!3m4!1m2!1d2.4590385!2d48.8039961!3s0x47e60cd1f00f4f39:0xeec27697049ce4a7!1m5!1m1!1s0x47e60cf1e2c1777d:0x3c10a4d85f6f80d2!2m2!1d2.4858453!2d48.798962!3e1), but can't find a way to export it as KML so I can import it into my Android smartphone.

Is there a way, or must directions be drawn in Google (Maps | MapsEngine)?

Comment: Can only be done via JSON as Google changed it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745314/why-retrieving-google-directions-for-android-using-kml-data-is-not-working-anymo/11745316#11745316

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scroll all the way to the bottom of the directions and click "Save to My Maps"/"Ajouter à "Mes cartes"".  You'll have to choose an existing map of yours or create a new one.  It will take you to your newly saved map and from there you can download the KML file.

Comment: Thanks. The "Save to My Maps" is only available when drawing a route in Google Maps, not plain Google. Thank you.

Comment: This feature was removed in Google Maps Classic, and is not available in Google Maps Engine Lite (a.k.a. "Google Maps New").

Answer (score -1):

Using https://www.google.com/mymaps has the option to export to KML or KMZ, but only if you built your directions in the mymaps interface.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].